# Can an animal have a body covered with "hearing" hair?

Tags: biology, xenobiology, fauna, senses

Since our ears have small hair inside which (at least partially) make it possible to hear, is it possible for an animal to have hearing based on hair on its whole body? Like highly specialized small hair used to hear, but rather than localized, spread out on the body?

Comment: As a comment, each hair should be in a small hole, and no longer than the hole's depth. Otherwise, the animal will hear a deafening sound every time a fly land on its back. It also gives you better directionality to pinpoint where the sound comes from. Be sure to protect them from water too, or your animal will have poor hearing when rain comes

Comment: @Akita, sorry for the late response, but would it work if the animal was covered with overlapping plates and the hair was just in-between them?

Comment: I guess it would.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Flies and other invertebrates posses already this [capability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichobothria): the little hairs they have on their bodies allow them to perceive pressure waves and react to them.

> Trichobothria (singular trichobothrium) are elongate setae ("hairs") present in arachnids, various orders of insects, and myriapods that function in the detection of airborne vibrations and currents, and electrical charge. In 1883, Friedrich Dahl observed that they were deflected by the sound waves from a violin and labelled them 'hearing hairs'.

That's why try catching a fly with your hand is difficult: the pressure waves produced by your moving hand warn the fly of where you trying to strike from.

Comment: It's not the only reason it's hard to catch a fly. They do have really fast reflexes, high time-resolution vision and are very good at calculating escape routes. But yes, the hairs are a big part of that, and it is the reason why fly swatters have holes.